# Minimum diameter of electromagnetic beam in terms of wavelength

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser

Is there a limit on the minimum diameter that a collimated electromagnetic beam must have (lasers or masers), in terms of its wavelength, or it is possible to create a beam with its diameter smaller than its wavelength?

edit: removed the plane wave sentence, as it was a misinterpretation of the dynamics of a laser beam.

Comment: If it's a plane wave,  then by definition it extends to infinity in the transverse directions, so its diameter is infinite.

Comment: Oh, I see. A source can only generate spherical waves, and this waves can be collimated with lensing.
In the case of lasers, what would be its minimum spot diameter, for a given wavelenght?

Comment: you should look up the term *gaussian beam*. There is a trade-off between the beam diameter and over what distance it remains collimated before diverging strongly.